# How not to let Home button quit your tvOS app in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, tvos, gamecontroller

In UIKit we can use GCEventViewController to intercept the game controllers from propagating Home button presses to the responders (and have them quit our app) by setting controllerUserInteractionEnabled = false

SwiftUI Apps do not use ViewControllers, so, except for resurrecting one to embed the whole app in it, we can't use the above solution to avoid the player leaving out game / app by accident by pressing the wrong button (not can we use buttonB)

Does anyone know a solution to this conundrum? Did Apple already implement a new way to intercept high-level events so we can deal with them internally?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You have to have a focusable view (like a button) and then you can use [onExitCommand](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onexitcommand(perform:)) in the containing view to simply ignore the exit event, or do something different.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Hello, world!") {
                
            }
        }.onExitCommand {
           // Do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Appreciate it, @Jeff !
Sorry I did not see your answer at the time, I ended up abandoning my pet project for other things. Guess I'll now get the dust off of it, and give your solution a go! 